# SQL Server Trigger - Insert the last updated date into table linked with foreign key

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have two tables, `ShoppingList` and `ShoppingListFood`. `ShoppingListFood` is linked to `ShoppingList` via a foreign key on `ShopListID`. I wish to update the `LastModifiedDate` column in the `ShoppingList` table whenever there is any update / insert done at the `ShoppingListFood` table. Is it possible??

I googled and found that I need create trigger in stored procedure, but i know nothing about it, can anyone help??

Comment: hi, thanks for reminding, but should i just mark the "best" answer or only mark the one which really solve my problem?? thanks..

Comment: hi, i do really appreciate help/feedback from everyone. I just not really "into" the way this thing works. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure - no problem - try something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_UpdateShoppingListFood
ON dbo.ShoppingListFood
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE dbo.ShoppingList
    SET LastModifiedDate = GETDATE()
    WHERE ShopListID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ShopListID FROM Inserted)
```

Basically, this creates a trigger that will fire after INSERT and UPDATE on `ShoppingListFood` - it will update the `LastModifiedDate` to "right now" for all rows that have been inserted and/or updated, based on the pseudo table `Inserted` that's available inside a trigger.

This pseudo table contains all rows that have been freshly inserted (with all their columns), as well as the new values for all rows that have been updated (again: all columns).

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I am trying it now. But do you have any idea why after i create and save the stored procedure in VS server explorer, I could not see the "expand" icon beside the Stored Procedure and I could not re-open the stored procedure i had just created???
Really thanks...

Comment: hi, i get the error: The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value
Any idea how to solve this??
Thanks..........

Comment: @user834754: no idea - something must be "out of bounds"... are you using Entity Framework? Are your columns in SQL Server of type `DATETIME` ?? Are you trying to insert a value something like `00-00-0000` or something like that????

Comment: hi, i able to clear this error if i change the data type of the LastUpdatedDate row to datetime(2). But i got no idea why I need to have the datetime2 instead of the usual datetime i used!

Comment: Hi, any idea why this trigger only works for create and edit, but not delete??? really thanks...

Comment: @user834754: this trigger is for **INSERT** and **UPDATE** - and definitely **NOT** for delete.... a DELETE trigger will have to look at the `Deleted` pseudo table for the rows that have been deleted...

Comment: so u mean i need to have another trigger for delete in order to update the date upon deletion?? Sorry for asking stupid question...

Comment: @user834754: **yes** - if you really need to update anything when deleting. And since it needs to inspect the `Deleted` pseudo table (instead of `Inserted`) you cannot just merge it into the existing trigger here - you need a separate trigger for the DELETE case

Comment: Thanks! i able to update the field after delete by 
CREATE TRIGGER trg_UpdateShopListOnDelete
ON dbo.SHOPLISTFOOD
AFTER DELETE
AS
    UPDATE dbo.SHOPLIST
    SET LastUpdatedDate = GETDATE()
    WHERE ShopListID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ShopListID FROM Deleted)